# How to access Files Locally using JCIFS?

Tags: jcifs

Currently its my windows machine. I am able to access files using shared network but when I try using local path it does not work. I want my code to work with local path like if my code is deployed in LINUX or windows I should be able to access files with local path and not shared network path.

```
NtlmPasswordAuthenticator sourceAuth = new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator("DOMAIN",
                "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.responseTimeout", "5000");
PropertyConfiguration configuration = new PropertyConfiguration(properties);
CIFSContext cifsContext = new BaseContext(configuration).withCredentials(sourceAuth);

SmbFile sourceDir = new SmbFile  (localSourceUrl,cifsContext);

localSourceUrl = smb://IPAddress/MYFOLDER works but
localSourceUrl = smb://IPAddress/C/MYFOLDER does not work
```

Error is jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

localSourceUrl = smb://IPAddress/C/MYFOLDER does not work as it
is not shared so will not work It does not show up when listing shares on pc

smb://IPAddress/MYFOLDER  will work as MYFOLDER will show as it is shared

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
localSourceUrl = smb://IPAddress/C$/MYFOLDER/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).